# Using index.php for whole pages slow

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, performance

I've  created the web site that i want to combine all pages in just one page in an `index.php` file. So, I've separated the page by using `if($_GET['page'])` and `index.php` file has contain to 15000 lines of code and it size is about 800 kB. Below is  my briefly `index.php` file.

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
   if(!$_GET['page']||$_GET['page']=="home"){
?>
<!--Inside this may have over 2000 lines of code, And include HTML or PHP code-->
<?
   }
?>

<?php
   if($_GET['page']=="blog"){
?>
<!--Inside this may have over 2000 lines of code, And include HTML or PHP code-->
<?
   }
?>

<?php
   if($_GET['page']=="discover"){
?>
<!--Inside this may have over 2000 lines of code, and include HTML or PHP code-->
<?
   }
?>

<?php
   if($_GET['page']=="user"){
?>
<!--Inside this may have over 2000 lines of code, and include HTML or PHP code-->
<?
   }
?>

<?php
   if($_GET['page']=="messages"){
?>
<!--Inside this may have over 2000 lines of code, and include HTML or PHP code-->
<?
   }
?>

<?php
   if($_GET['page']=="help"){
?>
<!--Inside this may have over 2000 lines of code, and include HTML or PHP code-->
<?
   }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

As I've told i thought this is not a good idea at all. And my problems became when it took long time to responses from server to client browsers. Sometimes it took `5-15 seconds` (this just happened sometimes or 30%) but normally it just use `10-100 ms` to responses. And I don't know the cause of this problem. It may because `index.php` too large? But why `JavaScript` library has over `8000 lines` or `CSS` has 3000 lines is not a problems. And if i change to this will it different from my previous? Please suggest better way to me as experienced that you have. Thank you.

```
<?php

$safeRoot = 'include/';

include 'header.php';

switch($_GET['page']){
case 'home':
include $safeRoot.'home.php';
break;
case 'blog':
include $safeRoot.'blog.php';
break;
case 'discover':
include $safeRoot.'discover.php';
break;
case 'user':
include $safeRoot.'user.php';
break;
case 'messages':
include $safeRoot.'messages.php';
break;
case 'help':
include $safeRoot.'help.php';
break;
default:
include $safeRoot.'home.php';
}

include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: TL;DR but here's a little tip: `if()` has an optional `else` clause. When you find what you're looking for, you can stop searching.

Comment: 1) Separate display from logic, your PHP code goes somewhere else unless it's explicitly doing something the user sees. 2) Consider simply removing anything that's not a letter from the page string, then include that file if it exists, rather than hard coding file names everywhere. 3) Consider using a plugin like APC to improve page times by caching PHPs parsed versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wont take 5-15sec even if code is of 15k lines(there do exist in many projects),Probably there is some loop which may cause problem or something handled incorrectly Please make errors on and check for errors.

debug your code and try finding which part of your code is taking more time,note the inputs which makes code slow and check the section of the code to be executed and then You can easily find out the real problem.

**NOTE:**
Use `if(isset($_GET['value'])){` instead of `if($_GET['value']){`
because if `$_GET['value']` value is 0 it wont work, and it will return error if it $_GET['value'] is not set when errors is turned on.

Comment: i'll try. Is this correct? `if(isset($_GET['value'])=="home"){`

Comment: no! use `if(isset($_GET['value'])&&$_GET['value']=="home"){`

Comment: @Marcus Just check the manual when in doubt: [isset()](http://php.net/isset) returns `true` or `false` so it's impossible that it'll ever be `'home'`.

Comment: Thanks to @Subhanker and everyone, I had changed them all to isset() and seems this is cause of my problem, I won't believe this little thing will enormously effected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a 800kb file would result in 5-15 seconds execution time.

I'd rather think one of the commands you are issuing is too slow.

To find out which one, you should messure the executon time in your script.

Put this at the start:

```
$time_start = microtime(true);
```

And this at different messure points in your script:

```
echo (microtime(true) - $time_start);
```

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket. Also better to use declare to avoid scoping issues.

Comment: yes, i done it and result execution time 10-100 ms and sometimes still 5-15 sec

Comment: But the question is: In between which commands does the execution time rise to 15sec? Don't just messure the time between start and end of your script. But also at different points in the middle of your script.